# String tokenizer to array java

Tags: java, arrays, file, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to import data from a file to array using string tokenizer.

Data format in file is

```
AA,BB,CC
AA,BB,CC
```

But i keep getting error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextElement(StringTokenizer.java:407)
    at main.main(main.java:36)
```

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input;
    String line;
    int x=0;
    String [] cName = new String [100];
    String [] cMascot = new String [100];
    String [] cAlias = new String [100];





         input = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

         while(input.hasNextLine()) {

             line = input.nextLine();
             StringTokenizer strings = new StringTokenizer(line,",");

             while (strings.hasMoreElements()) {
                 cName[x] = strings.nextElement().toString();
                 cMascot[x] = strings.nextElement().toString();
                 cAlias[x] = strings.nextElement().toString();
                 x++;
             }

         }


}

}
```

So any help would be appreciated. I cant use array list so that out of the context

Comment: If all lines have this format, why not just use `.split()`?

Comment: Shouldn't you check for `hasMoreElements()` before calling to each `nextElement()` ?

Comment: @fge I'm new to java so could tell me how would i go about it?

Comment: @the new idiot i do check for more elements "strings.hasMoreElements()"

Comment: You can always try debugging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `readLine` and `split` ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String line;
    int x=0;
    String [] cName = new String [100];
    String [] cMascot = new String [100];
    String [] cAlias = new String [100];

    try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileStreamReader("test.txt"))) {

         while ((line = input.readLine())!=null) {

             cName[x] = line.split(",")[0];
             cMascot[x] = line.split(",")[1];
             cAlias[x] = line.split(",")[2];
             x++;
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Quick question: String [] cName = new String [100]; say i dont know if need i need 100 array size, whats the best way to make it dynamic, so if i have 105elements, i can still save them in array

Comment: @user2291480 if you need dynamic array then use `ArrayList`.

Comment: Any way without ArrayList?

Comment: Hey how do i cast "year[z] = line.split(",")[0];" to int?

Comment: @user2291480 Try `Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[0])`

Answer (score 2):

you can't call .nextElement() many times in while statement;
befor each of them .hasNextLine() must be called

Comment: Yea. I got that now.. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you mean `hasMoreElements()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can have below code useful too :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input;
    String line;

    String cMascot = null;
    String cAlias = null;
    String cName = null;

    input = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        line = input.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer strings = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

        while (strings.hasMoreElements()) {
            cName = strings.nextToken();
            cMascot = strings.nextToken();
            cAlias = strings.nextToken();
            System.out.println("cName :" + cName);
            System.out.println("cMascot :" + cMascot);
            System.out.println("cAlias :" + cAlias);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, thansk for that but the Strings have to be arrays.